# Should I always prefer std::begin and std::end?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, containers

C++11 introduced free function overloads for `std::begin` and `std::end` that work on containers and arrays. When used on a container, `std::begin` will call the container's `begin` function. It seems to me then that there isn't a point in using `vect.begin()` anymore and `std::begin(vect)` should be used instead for consistency. Is there any reason not to prefer these (aside from compiling in older standard versions)?

Comment: I'd suggest `using std::begin; using std::end; begin(vect);`.

Comment: No, no reason at all. Prefer free functions over member functions.

Comment: I prefer `std::begin` and `std::end` for sexy codenz